# Store rsync error in variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, rsync

I've written a bash script to sync backups with a local storage, the script checks whether a backup as been made on the day the script is executed, and if so it sync's.

I've made it this way so that if by accident (or other way) all the backups are deleted from the original location, the synced backups on the second storage won't be deleted upon next sync.

```
#!/bin/bash
files_found=`ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx "find /home/data_folder/test* -type f -mtime -1"`

rsync_to_location="/home/test_folder/";     
rsync_from_location="/home/data_folder/";


if [ "$files_found" = 0 ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
    send_error=`ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx "echo 'This is the message body' | mail -s 'This is the subject' user@localhost"`
else
    echo "Files found!"
    rsync -arzt --ignore-existing --delete --max-delete=1 -e 'ssh' user@xx.xx.xx.xx:$rsync_from_location $rsync_to_location

    if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]; then
        send_error=`ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx "echo 'This is the message body' | mail -s 'This is the subject' earmaster@localhost"`
    fi
fi
```

Now my question is, if the rsync fails (max deletions), how can I store that message and send it with the mail?

I've tried with

```
rsync_error="rsync -arzt --ignore-existing --delete --max-delete=1 -e 'ssh' user@xx.xx.xx.xx:$rsync_from_location $rsync_to_location"
```

And then add the `$rsync_error` to the mail call, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you have put here will just store that command as a string and not run it.

```
rsync_error="rsync -arzt --ignore-existing --delete --max-delete=1 -e 'ssh' user@xx.xx.xx.xx:$rsync_from_location $rsync_to_location"
```

To capture its output you would need to put it in a `$( )` like so.

```
rsync_error=$(rsync -arzt --ignore-existing --delete --max-delete=1 -e 'ssh' user@xx.xx.xx.xx:$rsync_from_location $rsync_to_location)
```

This will capture the stdout of the executed command but you are wanting stderr I assume. So a better way of doing this might be to pipe to stderr to a file and handle the output that way.

```
# rsync err output file
ERR_OUTPUT="/tmp/rsync_err_$$"
# When the script exits, remove the file
trap "rm -f $ERR_OUTPUT" EXIT

# Use 2> to direct stderr to the output file
rsync -arzt --ignore-existing --delete --max-delete=1 -e 'ssh' user@xx.xx.xx.xx:$rsync_from_location $rsync_to_location 2> "$ERR_OUTPUT"

# Do what ever with your error file
```

Comment: Hi, the `rsync_error=$(...)` didn't work for me, but the second part did :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Epodax No problem :) I didn't expect the `$( )` bit to but I'm glad the other bit did :D